# Automatic save Printscreen video

Tags: ffmpeg, screenshot

I would like to save a screenshot of a video, as thumbnail image, as soon as someone uploads a video. They told me this is only possible on Windows servers. But now I read something about http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html. It looks like it creates the possibility to do the same on Linux, is that possible?
And does someone have experience with this?

Comment: yup its possible  http://321fame.com/ has same functionality  as you want , and this site also uses ffmpeg  and linux as server. my friend work on this site so i know about it.

Comment: Alright, thanks! I'll try installing it on debian

Comment: Who are "they"? Never listen to them again. This example command will make a thumbnail at ~30 seconds, [scale](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) it to 320 wide and automatically calculate height to preserve aspect, and give a decent quality (`-q:v` range is 1-31 where higher is worse quality): `ffmpeg -ss 30 -i input.mp4 -vf scale=320:-1 -q:v 4 -vframes 1 output.jpg`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, it works with Linux as ZIP told. 
I used LordNeckbeard's example for creating a screenshots, which works just fine!:

```
shell_exec(ffmpeg -ss 30 -i input.mp4 -vf scale=320:-1 -q:v 4 -vframes 1 output.jpg)
```